# Django python. Автоматическое скачивание файлов

Tags: python, django, файлы, автозагрузка

Суть в следующем: При изменении определенных полей формы записи на сайте, формируется документ, который автоматически заполняется данными с помощью библиотеки DocxTemplate. Документ появляется в папке проекта (там же, где лежит шаблон для формирования этого документа). Можно ли как-то реализовать загрузку этого сформированного файла средствами браузера? Чтобы загрузка происходила автоматически и файл помещался в стандартную папку Загрузки.
Не смог найти никакой информации по этому поводу, везде пишут только про загрузку по ссылке с помощью библиотеки requests.

Написал следующую функцию, она отрабатывает (проверял с помощью print в теле функции), но никакого скачивания не происходит.

```
def download_file(request):
    path = shorter_path + doc_name
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/msword')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + doc_name
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import mimetypes
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

def download(request):
file = 'path_to_file'
filename = os.path.basename(file)
chunk_size = 8192
response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(file, 'rb'), chunk_size),
                       content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(file)[0])
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file)    
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
return response
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600843/serving-large-files-with-high-loads-in-django)